# Is there a way to measure the degree of correlation between two posterior distributions?

Tags: distributions, correlation, descriptive-statistics, markov-chain-montecarlo, posterior

I have the following two distributions of MCMC samples from a Bayesian analysis and want to know the extent to which values from the first distribution are correlated with those from the second. Is there a way to measure this? If so, what is the standard way to do it?

[image: Distribution 1]

[image: Distribution 2]

Comment: Do you mean the extent to which these distributions are similar, the extent to which they gave outcomes the same probabilities? If they depict distributions for different outcomes and you want the distribution of one given the other, which would tell you all about how these outcomes are correlated, you can't get that from two marginal distributions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it then possible to measure the extent to which the distributions are similar, if correlation is not possible?